# Creating a dictionary like functionality in website - need help structuring JSON and HTTP calls

Tags: javascript, json, http

I'm trying to build a dictionary-like functionality into a website, but I'm not sure how to structure my JSON and HTTP calls. I have thought of two methods, and need help deciding which is best.

Let's say I have a long article, and I would like certain words to be clickable (and be bolded), and after I click it, a popup appears with the meaning of the word and an image explaining the word.

For example:

The **brown** fox **jumped** over the wall. Blah blah blah wall of text blah blah blah.

I've modelled the dictionary using the following format. We have only selected some words to include in our dictionary, and we have about 500 words in the dictionary, but the JSON that includes all the words would still be pretty big.

I've considered two methods to solve the problem, but not sure which is the best:

a) Initially, just load an array containing all the words in the dictionary, then test each word in the article against it.

```
['fox', 'cow', 'rat', ...]
//after it has been loaded, convert into a dictionary for faster matching
var dict = {fox:1, cow: 1, rat: 1};
//then test every word in the article and see if it exists in the dictionary (O(1) access?), and if the word exists, bold it
If the user clicks on a bolded word, do a XMLHttpRequest to get the full JSON of that word
```

The advantages of this method is faster loading time at the start, but each time the user clicks a word, it would require a server call.

b) The second method loads the whole dictionary (see below) initially, and then it's similar to the method above, just that when a user clicks a word, the user doesn't need to do a XMLHttpRequest and just needs to read from the initial JSON. This method is lower at the start, but much faster later on.

```
[
    {
        word: 'fox',
        explainerImageSrc: 'xxx.png',
        meaning: 'yyy'
    },
    {
        word: 'cow',
        explainerImageSrc: 'xxx.png',
        meaning: 'yyy'
    },
    xxx
]
```

Comment: Sounds like something you'd need to profile and decide which works better for you. There are too many unknowns for a definitive answer. If it's unlikely anybody is going to bother clicking your words, then the first method might be better. But if people are likely to click a lot of them, then the second is better. You could also go with a hybrid where you load the list of items first, and then load the definitions in the background so that by the time they click, it's probably already loaded.

Comment: How about loading the words, testing the text, and making an ajax call to load all the words found in the text.